# How to write pairwise similarity to an file in R programming

Tags: r, loops

I have a tab file: `string.tab`, which contain some think like below

```
Entry   String
Dog  cube;funny;smart
Cat  tiny;cube;black
....
```

I also have an package `Sim()` to compute the similarity between two vectors of string. For example

```
# here is demo to show how Sim() works
a = c("cs", "funny")
b = c("math", "cool")
score = Sim(a,b)
# output: 0.156
```

The details of `Sim()` is not important. It's just a text mining tool.

Here is my code:

```
data <- read.table("string.tab", sep="\t", header=TRUE)
```

Now the `string.tab` in stored in data.

My goal is to compute all pairwise similarity of Entry in `string.tab`

The output file `result` should be something like:

```
Entry1 Entry2 Score
dog cat 0.132
...
...
```

What is the fast way to do that?

Comment: So, you've read the data into R. Are you asking for help with the next step, splitting the strings? Or do you have that done and need help with the next step...

Comment: I only read the data into R, and ask for and need to split for the string by R. Above `a` and `b` are split by hand to show the demo of `Sim()`

Comment: Could you provide `dput(your_data)` or `dput(head(your_data))`?

Comment: @Ryan dput(head(data))
`structure(list(Entry = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Cat", 
"Dog", "human"), class = "factor"), String = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 2L), .Label = c("cube;funny;smart", "man;women", "tiny;cube;black"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `combn(seq(nrow(df)), 2)` to get all length 2 combinations (pairs) of row numbers. Then you can `apply` through these pairs a function which creates a data.frame for that pair, and then `rbind` the results together.

You can then save this as an `R` data file with `saveRDS`, as a CSV with `write.csv`, etc.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)

splits <- lapply(df$String, strsplit, ';')

pairs <- 
apply(utils::combn(seq(nrow(df)), 2), 2, function(x){
  data.frame(Entry1 = df$Entry[x[1]], Entry2 = df$Entry[x[2]], 
             Score = do.call(Sim, splits[x]))
})

pairs.df <- do.call(rbind, pairs)
pairs.df
#   Entry1 Entry2     Score
# 1    Dog    Cat 0.5791888
# 2    Dog  human 0.7434178
# 3    Cat  human 0.4850377

saveRDS(pairs.df, '/path/to/save/file.RDS')
#or
write.csv(pairs.df, '/path/to/save/file.csv')
```

Data / Functions Used

```
df <- structure(list(Entry = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Cat", "Dog", "human"), class = "factor"), String = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("cube;funny;smart", "man;women", "tiny;cube;black" ), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")


Sim <- function(x, y){ # example since I don't have real Sim
  set.seed(sum(nchar(x) + nchar(y)))
  runif(1)
}
```

Comment: cool structure. What if the `Sim(a, b, sem=hs, measure="mse")` has some argument to be set. Will it work?

Comment: Sure, one option would be to define `Sim2 <- function(x, y) Sim(x, y, sem = hs, measure = 'mse')` then just replace `Sim` with `Sim2` inside `apply`

Comment: To call directly in apply, replace `do.call(Sim, splits[x]))` with `Sim(splits[[x[1]]], splits[[x[2]]], sem = hs, measure = 'mse')`

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward thing would be to write a for loop.

I'm going to assume you have some method/function to make a vector from `data$String` given an index. In this example i'll name the function `extract()`

```
 l <- nrow(data)
 n <- choose(l, 2) # number of combinations made
 entry <- data$entry
 result <- data.frame(Entry1 = rep("",n), Entry2 = rep("",n), Score = rep(0,n))
#make combination data
.comb <- data.frame(Entry1 = rep(0,n), Entry2 = rep(0,n))

#Entry1 list
.comb$Entry1 <- unlist(mapply(FUN = rep, x = 1:l, times = (l-1):0))
#Entry2 list
.c <- c(2:l)
if(l>2){
  for(i in 3:l) {
  .c <- c(.c,i:l)
  }
}
.comb$Entry2 <- .c


for(i in 1:n) {
   result[i,"Entry1"] <- data$Entry1[.comb[i,"Entry1"]]
   result[i,"Entry2"] <- data$Entry2[.comb[i,"Entry2"]]
   e.1 <- extract(data$String[.comb[i,"Entry1"]])
   e.2 <- extract(data$String[.comb[i,"Entry2"]])
   result[i, "Score"] <- Sim(e.1,e.2)
}
```